# Require Bronze Badge in Tag to Close Question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, badges

I feel like this may be a duplicate, but I wouldn't know the correct term(s) to search regarding this.

As of now, I'm able to vote to close questions in any tag, even if I have no experience in that tag whatsoever.  I understand why it may be helpful, but many (especially on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/8c61bk/asking_a_question_on_stackoverflow_in_a_nutshell/dxcpkdy/)) see it as an abuse of power.

For that reason, I propose that users with at least a bronze badge in a tag should be allowed to vote to close questions.  To me, having a score of at least 100 proves that you have enough experience with a concept in order to determine if it's off-topic, opinion-based, etc.

Though, if this were to be implemented, I can see how it would interfere with the Review Queue.

Comment: That'll make new tags a PAIN., And lower traffic tags tough to moderate.

Comment: Then who's gonna close [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile) or [jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jobs) or [kali-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux) questions as off-topic?

Comment: Claiming that close voters don't have the domain knowledge necessary to close is often just an excuse to dismiss the close votes because the user is in denial or sees their question as perfect. It's actually very rare to need domain knowledge to know something is off-topic or opinion-based or even just way too broad. The argument that close voters "just don't understand the topic" is completely untrue.

Comment: "StackOverflow’s reward system incentivizes users to close questions in order to earn more points and badges." This is the first sentence quoted from your Reddit thread. How to earn "more points and badges" by closing ? They know *nothing* about how close vote works. I'm surprised that a seasoned user will be swayed by these nonsense posts.

Comment: @liliscent I was mainly referring to "I once saw someone close an iOS question who had only answered Ruby questions."

Comment: On a personal note, I have a bronze badge in Java, despite never having written a single line of Java in my life:)   I don't need actual langage skills to detect many kinds of bad questions.  I can accurately down and close vote a requirement dump in jQuery, Java or PL/1 :)

Comment: *especially on Reddit* ... Don't we have enough problems of our own?

Comment: You don't always need domain knowledge to recognize a terrible question.

Answer (score 13):

What about the cases where the question is clearly off topic for any one of the standard close reasons? For example:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

or

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

(to quote just two)

These require no domain knowledge on behalf of the user to be able to be used, and nor should they.

Even some duplicate questions can be determined without domain knowledge (though I would steer clear of those even before I was a moderator).

Comment: I'd say duplicates are a finer line. I'd be comfortable closing a question that is a clear repost, but those don't come up all that often.